# thread.join() not working in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am making a GUI in Python Tkinter. My problem is thread.join() is not working as expected.

Main App:

```py
  self.path = r'src\files\iki'
  # Threads
        
  self.play_video(self.path)
  print("worked")
    
  def play_video(self, path):
    self.threads: [threading.Thread] = []
        
    self.video_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.video_player.play_video, args=(self.path + ".mp4",))
    self.sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.video_player.play_sound, args=(self.path + ".mp3",))

    self.threads.append(self.video_thread)
    self.threads.append(self.sound_thread)
        
    self.sound_thread.start()
    self.video_thread.start()

    for thread in self.threads:
      if thread.is_alive():
        thread.join()
```

Script File;

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk

import pygame
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo


class VideoPlayerWithSound(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent_frame):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent_frame = parent_frame
        self.video_path = None
        self.is_playing = False
        
        self.videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=self.parent_frame, scaled=True)
        self.videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        
        pygame.init()

    def play_video(self , video_path):
        self.videoplayer.load(video_path)
        self.videoplayer.play()
    
    def play_sound(self, sound_path):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(sound_path)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

The above code should print "worked" after my threads are done, but it did not print anything.

I tried making this thread in another script file, but the result was the same.

Comment: It seems that the sound and/or the video thread don't terminate.

Comment: @MichaelButscher How can i terminate it

Comment: The target functions `play_video` and `play_audio` must return (or raise an exception).

Comment: It seems `Thread-2 (play_video)` not finished maybe because of the video still running but why doesn't `sound_thread` showed. i couldn't find any solutions @MichaelButscher

Comment: Can you give us a [mre]? Right now we have no idea how `play_video`/`play_audio` work. Like MichaelButscher pointed out, it seems like the code in one of the 2 (or both) threads doesn't stop running which means the `.join` will never finish. Why do you need the `.join()` in the first place?

Comment: @TheLizzard updated can you check again

Comment: Try adding a `print` statements inside `play_video`/`play_audio`. Which one of the 2 gets stuck? Looking at the source code for [`TkinterVideo.play`](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/51966f3125103ca62d15dcef1015828ae3c03596/tkVideoPlayer/tkvideoplayer.py#L225C20-L225C20), it doesn't look like it it is the one getting stuck. Is your `print("worked")` just after the `self.play_video(self.path)`? Also it should be `.join()` not `.Join()`

Comment: i edited i wrote wrong. No one is getting stuck both of them working and printed the given text. I just cant understand why does my join working @TheLizzard

Comment: If none of them are getting stuck, it must be because both `pygame.mixer.music.play` and `TkinterVideo.play` run in their own threads. So the joins worked, the threads just died after starting new threads. For example if you look at the source code of [`TkinterVideo.play`](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/51966f3125103ca62d15dcef1015828ae3c03596/tkVideoPlayer/tkvideoplayer.py#L225C20-L225C20), it starts a new thread (in the background without stopping your code from running) and updates the screen with the video. If you don't want that, add a loop waiting for the vid to stop.

Comment: I tried to find which thread is current while sound and video playing , with threading(on my own) it shows my own thread. without threading it shows main thread. How can i make loop @TheLizzard

Comment: Instead of writing a loop (which can get messy because of `tkinter`), why not put all of the code that is called after `play_video` in a new function and use `self.video_player.bind("<<Ended>>", <your function>)`. `TkinterVideo` will call your function just after it is done playing the video. [This](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/51966f3125103ca62d15dcef1015828ae3c03596/tkVideoPlayer/tkvideoplayer.py#L206) is the line of code that will call your function when the video has finished playing.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank a lot man i am working on it like 10 hours and you made it. Thanks for attention !